# Javascript перебрать json

Tags: javascript, json, foreach

Имею JSON такого вида:

```
[{"Id":"110","Fam":"Вальков","Name":"Илья","Lastname":"Васильевич","FullName":"Вальков Илья Васильевич ","Datebirth":"17.05.2017","DateRecord":"13.05.2017","Lgotcat":"ТТ","DateInvitation":"27.05.2017"},{"Id":"111","Fam":"Федоров","Name":"Евгения","Lastname":"Юрьевич","FullName":"Федоров Евгения Юрьевич ","Datebirth":"18.05.2017","DateRecord":"13.05.2017","Lgotcat":"ТТ","DateInvitation":"31.05.2017"},{"Id":"112","Fam":"Кайзер","Name":"Илья","Lastname":"Юрьевич","FullName":"Кайзер Илья Юрьевич ","Datebirth":"11.05.2017","DateRecord":"13.05.2017","Lgotcat":"УВОВ","DateInvitation":"26.05.2017"},{"Id":"104","Fam":"Васильева","Name":"Анжелика","Lastname":"Валерьевна","FullName":"Васильева Анжелика Валерьевна ","Datebirth":"05.01.1957","DateRecord":"08.05.2017","Lgotcat":"ВТ","DateInvitation":"10.05.2017"},{"Id":"108","Fam":"Петро","Name":"Вадим","Lastname":"Викторович","FullName":"Петро Вадим Викторович ","Datebirth":"11.05.2017","DateRecord":"11.05.2017","Lgotcat":"ВТ","DateInvitation":"19.05.2017"},{"Id":"109","Fam":"Димидов","Name":"Евгений","Lastname":"Олегович","FullName":"Димидов Евгений Олегович ","Datebirth":"12.05.2017","DateRecord":"11.05.2017","Lgotcat":"ВТ","DateInvitation":"28.05.2017"}]
```

Нужно создать массив, или другой JSON со всеми видами Lgotcat полученными из 
исходного JSON.

А также посчитать количество записей по каждой Lgotcat

Как мне видится, что-бы это реализовать нужно в цикле перебрать все Lgotcat из 
JSON и проверять на уникальность каждого и добавлять в массив типа типа string.

А потом еще одним циклом выводить количество записей по каждой категории.

Может есть более подходящее решение под мою задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var jsn = '[{"Id":"110","Fam":"Вальков","Name":"Илья","Lastname":"Васильевич","FullName":"Вальков Илья Васильевич ","Datebirth":"17.05.2017","DateRecord":"13.05.2017","Lgotcat":"ТТ","DateInvitation":"27.05.2017"},{"Id":"111","Fam":"Федоров","Name":"Евгения","Lastname":"Юрьевич","FullName":"Федоров Евгения Юрьевич ","Datebirth":"18.05.2017","DateRecord":"13.05.2017","Lgotcat":"ТТ","DateInvitation":"31.05.2017"},{"Id":"112","Fam":"Кайзер","Name":"Илья","Lastname":"Юрьевич","FullName":"Кайзер Илья Юрьевич ","Datebirth":"11.05.2017","DateRecord":"13.05.2017","Lgotcat":"УВОВ","DateInvitation":"26.05.2017"},{"Id":"104","Fam":"Васильева","Name":"Анжелика","Lastname":"Валерьевна","FullName":"Васильева Анжелика Валерьевна ","Datebirth":"05.01.1957","DateRecord":"08.05.2017","Lgotcat":"ВТ","DateInvitation":"10.05.2017"},{"Id":"108","Fam":"Петро","Name":"Вадим","Lastname":"Викторович","FullName":"Петро Вадим Викторович ","Datebirth":"11.05.2017","DateRecord":"11.05.2017","Lgotcat":"ВТ","DateInvitation":"19.05.2017"},{"Id":"109","Fam":"Димидов","Name":"Евгений","Lastname":"Олегович","FullName":"Димидов Евгений Олегович ","Datebirth":"12.05.2017","DateRecord":"11.05.2017","Lgotcat":"ВТ","DateInvitation":"28.05.2017"}]';
var data = JSON.parse(jsn);
var cats = {};
data.forEach(function(v) {
  if(v.Lgotcat in cats) {
    cats[v.Lgotcat]++;
  } else {
    cats[v.Lgotcat] = 1;
  }
});
console.log(cats);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = JSON.stringify(сюда вложи свой не совсемJSON); 
var a = JSON.parse(a).map(function(i) {
    return i.Lgotcat}); //получишь массив с Lgotcat;
```

далее не совсем понятно что считать =)

Comment: в массив в таком случае, попадают все категории, а они не должны дублироваться
<br/>
далее не совсем понятно что считать =)
<br/>
Посчитать количество записей по каждой из категорий

Comment: var set = new Set();
a.forEach(function(e) {
 set.add(e)});

Comment: set - будет содержать значения без повторов , можно потом их все переместить в массив, если нужно через forEach(не знаю как править тут комментарии, что отображались в нормальном виде _((()

Comment: а как тогда посчитать количество всех повторов каждого из элементов?